# how do I do this in Excel. I used this to work for column A but I also want to do additional columns

Tags: excel, vba

How do I do this in Excel? I used this to work for column A but I also want to do additional columns

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim T As Range, r As Range
    Set T = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
    If T Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In T
        With r
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value + .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With
    Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you change "A:A" to the columns, it'll run on those.  I will work on a macro that prompts you for those though, if it works like you want if you do, say, "B:B".

Comment: Right now i have it running in column B and adding the value to column C and then resetting B back to zero. I also want it to perform in the following columns f,g  j,k  n,o  r,s  v,w  z,aa

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim T As Range, r As Range
Dim columnArray() As String, columnsToCopy As String
Dim i As Integer

columnsToCopy = InputBox("What columns (A,B,C, etc.) would you like to copy the data of?  Use SPACES, to separate columns")
columnArray() = Split(columnsToCopy)

For i = LBound(columnArray) To UBound(columnArray)
    Set T = Intersect(Target, Range("" & columnArray(i) & ":" & columnArray(i) & "")) 'Columns(columnArray(i)) & ":" & Columns(columnArray(i))))
    If T Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In T
        With r
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value + .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With
    Next r
Next i
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

That will create a popup, asking you for the columns you want to run this on.  What's the thought behind running this every time a cell changes? That's going to be a lot of pop-ups, etc.  But let me know if this doesn't work or has some error.

Comment: This works. The only issue is i have is 77 pop ups for all the cells it has to be run on.

Comment: @Bobby - Do you need it to be a worksheet_Change event? Why not just make it a regular macro, and you choose when to run it.  Why are there 77 pop ups? Are you changing an input each time?